# How to access NSURLSession temp file in UIWebview local HTML file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, filepath, nsurlsession

I have downloaded a json file (`data.json`) using NSURLSession. I am trying to access this file from a local html file (main project folder) `myfile.html` which is displayed via UIWebView. From NSLog I have identified the temp file location is here:

`file:///Users/administrator/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/166B438D-4F67-448C-B0E5-B32438DA3BF9/data/Containers/Data/Application/FCA61482-BC5D-4804-91F8-891EAB4DB145/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_g6961Q.tmp`

My question is how should I access this temp file from the local 'top level' html file, using a relative path?

More generally therefore - how does one access the iOS application file structure from such a top level (relative to the project) html file?

Some background info:

1. When I manually copy `data.json` to XCode and access it from `myfile.html` using the relative path `'data.json'` it works.
2. The download code is:

   ```
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/data.json"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session     downloadTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:
   ^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {      
   }
   ```
3. The reason I am doing this with NSURLSession is that I can't do it with Javascript in the html file since it is a cross domain request.

EDIT: Thanks for the helpful answers about adding HTML as a string into the UIWebView. I can see that trying to reference a temp file from the local HTML file is a bit unwieldly and may run counter to Apple's preference of not exposing filepaths - but I am still interested in a definitive answer on whether it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could inject the JSONData into the web page once it has finished loading within the web view. Something like this (I have not tested it):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/data.json"];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (!error && result.length > 0)
    {
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var jsonData = \"%@\"", result]];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Oops: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can either. Instead of loading your resource HTML as-is, use it as a "template" and put a "placeholder" string where you need the link to your temp file.

Then, load your HTML into a (mutable) string, replace the placeholder for the actual path to the file and pass this modified HTML string to your web view.